# Use UISlider without user interaction

Tags: ios, uislider, uicontrol

I've got a customized UISlider that I want to use to display information to the user with and I don't want the user to be able to interact with the slider. I've tried

```
mySlider.enabled = NO;
```

but the slider becomes greyed out, which does not look the way I want it to look.

So, how do I set a UIControl to disabled without "greying" it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
mySlider.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: it just stop calling its functions associated with it. it do not stop slider to move;

Answer (score 2):

Don't you think it's going to confuse users to present an enabled slider that doesn't respond to touches? A UISlider doesn't just display information, it also tells the user that the information is user-adjustable.

You should come up with your own information display that doesn't look user-adjustable.

Comment: I totally agree, however in this case it's been customized, so it looks more like a progress bar and not something the user can interact with.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I missed the word "customized" in your question and was picturing a stock UISlider.

Answer (score 0):

userInteractionEnabled probably doesn't works for the UISlider (and why it exists??) but it works for its superview. So, try attaching the UISlider to another auxiliary (transparent?) NSView and then set userInteractionEnabled = NO to this auxiliary view.